# How can an average rate of change be smaller, yet the function be larger?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**Torty, the Tortoise and Harry the Hare question.**

[Problem Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LMYE.png)

> [This question] centers around the following situation, describing a 100m race.  [...]
> Situation: Torty and Harry are competing in a 100m sprint race.
> **Torty's average speed on any 5 second interval is always less than Harry's average speed on any 5 second interval, but Torty wins the race!**
> (Note: for consistency, let's say they keep running after 100 meters so that their speeds can always be calculated by looking forward in time, but we stop the race at 100 meters.)
> Prompt: Discuss as a group (using the definitions of constant and average rate of change) how it is possible that Torty wins the race.
> Post an initial conjecture by describing the properties of Torty's and Harry's distance-time relationships that would allow for Torty to win under the constraints of the race.
> [...] specifically address how properties of Torty and Harry's distance-time relationships do or do not match with the definitions of constant and average rate of change and and do or do not fit the constraints of the race.
> [...] create a neatly drawn or computer generated graph that shows Torty's and Harry's distance-time relationships that visualize the described race.

Some context- I am a tutor.  This question has come up at least a couple of times from students.  Most recent is a student at Embry Riddle University.  Due to constraints with my employer, this is most of what I know about the context, no ability to ask any more clarifying questions, etc.  It's probably safe to assume Calculus I methods, so little or no analysis.  This is an education context, so the answer should probably incorporate "how their described properties of Torty and Harry's distance time relationships do or do not match with the definition of constant and average rate of change and do or do not fit the constraints of the race."

My answer- Torty gets a head start.
Any other graph I can think of with Torty winning the race has Torty has a higher average rate of change over at least one 5 second interval.

Also, note "Torty's average speed on any 5 second interval is always less than Harry's average speed on any 5 second interval."  implies A. strictly less than, not equal to and B. The words any could compare unlike intervals.  For example, compare Harry's first 5 seconds, with Torty's last 5 seconds, etc.

Comment: I'm retyping the image into the problem now.

Comment: Unsure what you are asking, so unsure if my response is on point.  Consider the graph of $f(x) = \log(x) ~: ~x \geq 1.$  Then $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, whose derivative, $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is always positive.  However, $f'(x)$ is itself a strictly decreasing function.  Geometrically, the explanation is simply that the graph of $f(x)$ is concave (i.e. curved downward).

Comment: no, the question doesn't say anything about 2nd deriv., concavity, etc.

Comment: I was reacting to your posting's title : "How can an average rate of change be smaller, yet the function be larger?".  The example that I offered has $f(x)$ strictly increasing, while the rate of change (AKA the first derivative) is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Related (not directly applicable): Aesop's fable of [the tortoise and the hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tortoise_and_the_Hare).  In this story, the hare stops mid-race to take a nap...

Comment: @user2661923 : The title is not the Question.  The title *could* be clearer since it is distinct functions described in the two clauses.

Comment: You copied wrong the text from the image

Comment: @jjagmath  where?  I'll reread it in a minute.

Comment: @EricTowers Agreed.  However, I was unable to decipher a question from his posting, so I took a guess as to what might be a helpful response.  Hence the start of my comment: "Unsure what you are asking, so unsure if my response is on point. "

Comment: The "sentence" starting "Torty's average speed" is missing some text

Comment: @RossMillikan  Thanks, I wondered why people were missing that constraint in the comments.  LOL.  Fixed it.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Tough to fix or improve if I don't know why.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is a better fit on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: Anyone else who thinks this should be migrated?  How do I go about migrating it?

Comment: Halfway through the race Harry realizes he left a shoe back at the starting line, so he runs at top speed back and starts over. His *speed* is always greater than Torty's, but his (vector) *velocity* is sometimes negative.

Comment: Harry runs two-and-a-half seconds towards the finish line at, say, 10 miles per hour, then runs two-and-a-half seconds back toward the starting line at the same speed. His speed is a constant 10mph, so it averages 10mph over every five second interval (in fact, over any interval of any length). Torty runs at a constant four mph, but always towards the finish line. Torty's average speed over every five second interval is smaller than Harry's, but Torty wins the race. (Ah, @Barry beat me to it.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson, great minds?

Comment: @Barry, if only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer is that Torty runs the 100m in 4 seconds, then stops running.  Harry runs the 100m in 4.1 seconds, then another 10m in the last 0.9 seconds.  Torty averages 20m/sec, Harry averages 22m/sec and there is only one interval to compare.

Comment: hmmm, at first glance that seems to disagree with "they keep running after 100m".  implies at least positive velocity.  Perhaps it can be tweaked, maybe Torty "runs" 1 meter in the last 0.9 s.

Comment: Yes, that will work.  I took "keep running" just to mean we keep counting, but a slight positive velocity for Torty is fine.

Comment: Actually, there are still multiple intervals, [1,6],  [2,7], [3,8], [4,9] and those with decimal or irrational endpoints etc.   But we can probably show Harry's avg. is faster in those intervals also.

Comment: We just keep Harry faster than Torty ever was for all time after they finish the race.

Comment: I'll give it a few days, see what other answers come along, then probably give you credit for the answer.  Mind if I add something along the lines of "We can even prepend both running at practically the same speed to make this realistic."  As it stands, 22m/s is about human double world record times.

Comment: @RossMillikan : Hi Ross, quick terminology question: , is there really a difference between *a rate* and *a rate of change*? If they are the same thing, could we define both by saying *a rate/a rate of change is the ratio between two related quantities in different units*?

Comment: @TaylorRendon  They are similar and can have the same units.  When Harry is running we can describe his speed as the rate he runs at.  It is also the rate of change of his position.  They are both expressed in units of velocity.  Dividing them does not really make sense.

Comment: @RossMillikan - oops, what I actually meant by "*a rate/a rate of change is...*" was "*a rate **and** a rate of change is...*", *i.e.,* they are both defined by what follows; not division :-). In that vein, so there isn't a difference in a rate and a rate of change? Thank you for your time, as well.

Comment: I don't see a significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

A more general way (than Ross Millikan's answer) that this can work is something like the following. Torty runs $11\,\mathrm{ms}^{-1}$ for one second, then $1\,\mathrm{ms}^{-1}$ for four seconds, then repeats. This means averaging $3\,\mathrm{ms}^{-1}$ for each $5$-second interval, but finishing in just under $31$ seconds (covering $101\,\mathrm{m}$ in $31\,\mathrm{s}$). Harry, meanwhile, runs at a steady speed of $3.125\,\mathrm{ms}^{-1}$, beating Torty on any $5$-second interval, but finishing in exactly $32\,\mathrm{s}$.

After $30$ seconds Harry is ahead (inevitably), and after $35$ seconds Harry is ahead, but in between Torty is briefly ahead, and this coincides with the winning post.

Comment: I suspect this is the intended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Harry reaches the same 100 meter point but takes a curve or zig zig. They said he speed over 5 seconds but not 5 meters.

Also the Tortoise could have been shot out of a cannon.

But your head start idea means he didn't run 100 meters.

Comment: "head start" can mean that the Torty starts on time and proceeds slowly, while Harry arrives at the race late, speeds along the track, but doesn't catch Torty before Torty wins.  Harry doesn't have an average speed prior to starting the race.

Comment: "Doesn't"= Zero // Slow > Zero.

Comment: "Does not exist" ${}\neq 0$.

Comment: the average speed is based on time.  I suspect the time Harry has zero speed at the beginning will make this not work.  'Compare any of Harry's intervals with any of Torty's intervals.'

Comment: While we're looking for alternative interpretations: possibly (a) Harry was going the wrong way or (b) disqualified for doping